# Why does $\langle a \rangle \langle b \rangle \subset \langle ab \rangle$ in a commutative ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

My friend and I saw this affirmation in a proof and we're having trouble figuring out why is this valid.

Thanks in advance!

Sorry: forgot to add some details. Consider a commutative ring A and an ideal prime I of A. We have $a,b \in I$.

Comment: Surely $\left<a\right>\left<b\right>=\left<ab\right>$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown sorry, forgot to add some details. $a,b \in I$, where I is an ideal prime of a commutative ring A.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, we have elements of $(a)(b)$ are finite sums of the form
$$\sum r_ias_ib$$
for some $r_i,s_i\in A$. By commutativity, we have
$$\sum r_ias_ib=\sum r_is_iab=\sum l_iab$$
for some $l_i\in A$.

Then $\sum l_iab\in (ab)$ clearly.

We don't need primeness of $I$.